# Mule/Soap without internet: Unable to locate imported document at 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, jax-ws, mule-component

What are the possibles causes this error when a SOAP Web Service (used into Sugarcrm component) is called?
I am using Mule 3.7.0 CE.

In my local machine works on Anypoint Studio and Windows. But when I put into server Linux, this error occurs:

> 2016-08-17 16:40:42,201 [pool-115-thread-1] ERROR org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier - Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: Unable to locate imported document at 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', relative to 'jar:file:/usr/mule/mule-standalone-3.7.0/tmp/teclogica-projeto/plugins/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3/lib/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3.jar!/schema/sugarcrm.wsdl#types1'.. Type: class org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException
>   2016-08-17 16:40:42,219 [pool-115-thread-1] ERROR org.mule.exception.RollbackMessagingExceptionStrategy -
>
> ---
>
> Message               : Failed to invoke getEntryList. Message payload is of type: GetEntryListRequest
>
> ### Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
>
> Exception stack is:
>   1. Unable to locate imported document at 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', relative to 'jar:file:/usr/mule/mule-standalone-3.7.0/tmp/teclogica-projeto/plugins/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3/lib/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3.jar!/schema/sugarcrm.wsdl#types1'. (org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException)
>     org.apache.cxf.catalog.CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver:76 (null)
>   2. Failed to create service. (org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException)
>     org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory:183 (null)
>   3. org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service. (javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException)
>     org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl:347 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceException.html)
>   4. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service. (java.lang.RuntimeException)
>     com.zauberlabs.commons.ws.connection.ConnectionBuilder:142 (null)
>   5. java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service. (java.lang.RuntimeException)
>     org.mule.modules.sugarcrm.exception.ExceptionFactory:35 (null)
>   6. Failed to invoke getEntryList. Message payload is of type: GetEntryListRequest (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>
> ### org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor:133 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
>
> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Unable to locate imported document at 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', relative to 'jar:file:/usr/mule/mule-standalone-3.7.0/tmp/teclogica-projeto/plugins/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3/lib/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3.jar!/schema/sugarcrm.wsdl#types1'.
>       at org.apache.cxf.catalog.CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.resolveEntity(CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.java:76)
>       at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:684)
>
> ---

REV.

My local machine does not work too, when it is without internet.

How to know what link/reaource exactly it need? Is there a form to configurate  an internal file (without Internet needs)?

Comment: Cross the wsdl which you have uploaded initially in CXF(SOAP) is placed in 'src/main/resource' or deleted. It should present in your `classpath` or pointing to  system location?.

Comment: I am using SugarCRM component that does use of the SOAP.  I explored on project in the library mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3.jar/META-INF/mule-sugar.xsd and see the has a 'link:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd"' but actually we have available on web the '"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.7/mule.xsd"' with the version in path. Could be this the problem?

Comment: This problem is strange. In my PC (Windows) into Anystudio works fine, but when I put the app on Server (Linux) the problem occurs.

Comment: About `classpath` I used the 'Build Path' of the Anypoint Studio and seleted all paths, libs e jar... And nothing!

Comment: In Linux Server, the Sugar Library is deployed <mule home>/apps/app-name/plugins/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3.zip AND <mule home>/tmp/teclogica-projeto/plugins/mule-module-sugarcrm-1.0.3/lib

Comment: The root cause is that the app does not work without internet. I edited the question to put this information. How could I embeded definitions the web service in Mule App (or on server)?

Comment: You have build your project with Maven dependency? If so, it will import jars from  central repository which need internet. If you don't want it though, you can build your local Intranet repository, where you can point it.

Comment: If you dont want that too. By default on installing Anypoint Studio, Mule provides as inbuilt RunTime  which need not require internet or Intranet. On deployment in server in these cases you need your reference library bundled with your application. Reference: ( check Benefits  ) https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-maven-with-mule

Comment: I do not use the Maven. I just build it with local library.

Comment: If your project requirement dont use Maven. Importing the required libraries into your packaged applications manually for  deployment.This means, all your required Libraries needs to be in your application. ( If you use Maven,it download in from repository else we need to add it in package). Hope it clears you.